# How to find points of extrema of $f(x)=\cos x+ \cos\left(\sqrt{2}x\right)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, convergence-divergence, continuity

How to find points of extrema of $f(x)=\cos x+ \cos\left(\sqrt{2}x\right)$

we have $$f'(x)=-\sin x - \sqrt{2}\sin\left(\sqrt{2}x \right)=0 \tag{1}$$

$x=0$ is one of the solutions at which $f$ attains local Maximum since

$$f''(x)=-\left(\cos x+2 \cos\left(\sqrt{2}x\right)\right)$$ we have$f''(0) \lt 0$

But $1$ has infinite solutions right, how to check whether they are points of Local Maxima and Minima?

Comment: yes thanks i edited accordingly

Answer (score 1):

HINT: use that $$\cos(x)+\cos(\sqrt{2}x)=2\cos\left(\frac{x-\sqrt{2}x}{2}\right)\cos\left(\frac{x+\sqrt{2}x}{2}\right)$$

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, it doesn't seem so obvious how to use your hint.

Comment: Ask yourself: 1) what is the max of $\cos x$? 2) what is the max of the product of two $\cos$ functions? 3) can you achieve that maximum?

Comment: @player100 Are you talking to me?